# DataGridView databound and manual column

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` on a form in c#, of the 7 columns i need on this DGV 6 of them will be pulled from an SQL DB and 1 of them i need to manually enter and its a link column . One thing i have going for me (i think) is that the  manual column have the same data in every row.

I have been filling this DGV using a datatable, but i am not figuring out how to add manual columns and data bound ones in the same DGV. My column layout would look like this:

> Column1 - DB Populated
>
> Column2 - DB Populated
>
> Column3 - DB Populated
>
> Column4 - DB Populated
>
> Column5 - DB Populated
>
> Column6 - DB Populated
>
> Column7 - Manually Populated

Can someone please explain to me how i would do something like this. if you can include the datatable definitions also it would be a big help, in order for me to verify that i am at least doing that the right way.

Comment: Is there any **corresponding column to the manually added column** in the underlying data source (`DataTable`)?

Comment: No. the value in the manually populated colomn (for all rows) is "View Details" which is a Link colomn. it has no connection with the DB populated values

Comment: If so, you don't need the so-called `manually bound column`, because we don't have any underlying data source to bind to, why not set the cell values manually in the added column? Or you have some other data source from which to pull data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not know why this should be so difficult - do not keep any columns initially in the Datagrid. Bind it to a datasource and then add your columns manually

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from yourtable", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("manualcolumn", "manualcolumn");
}
```

Alternatively:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from yourtable", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("manualcolumn", "manualcolumn");
}
```

`con` is `SqlConnection`